# How to create array of strings in one line?

Tags: ruby

Is there a way to create an array with the values `NN`, `NNN`, `NNNN`, `NNNNN`, `NNNNNN` in one line in Ruby?

I've already got

```
array = Array.new(7) { |i| ("N"*i).to_s }
```

but that includes `""` and `"N"`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 8):

You could try:

```
5.times.map { |i| 'N' * (i+2) }
```

Or even better:

```
(2..6).map { |i| 'N' * i }
```

With your approach:

```
Array.new(5) { |i| 'N' * (i+2) }
```

Comment: Ah yes, that's it. So simple :-) Thanks.

Comment: @Tintin81 no problem, would be a pleasure for me to get mark as right answer to your question)